# extjs 4.2 themeing with sencha cmd and sass: How do I match up the sass variable with the css property

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sass

For example I want to be able to change the form trigger color from its default color to a custom color.  It appears that I only have access to the variable the from-trigger-border-bottom styling in Trigger.scss:

```
$form-trigger-width: 17px !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-width: 1px !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-style: solid !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-color: $form-field-border-color !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom: $form-trigger-border-bottom-width $form-trigger-border-bottom-style $form-trigger-border-bottom-color !default;

$form-trigger-border-bottom-color-over: adjust-color($base-color, $hue: -4.322deg, $saturation: -1.065%, $lightness: -16.863%) !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-color-focus: adjust-color($base-color, $hue: -4.322deg, $saturation: -1.065%, $lightness: -16.863%) !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-color-focus-over: null !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-color-pressed: null !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override those variables in your sass/scss file. do it on top of the import
right now probably your sass files looks something like this

```
@import 'ext4/default/all';
```

you need to call those variable before the import

```
$form-trigger-width: 17px !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-width: 1px !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-style: solid !default;
$form-trigger-border-bottom-color: $form-field-border-color !default;
@import 'ext4/default/all';
```

of course change the values to do what you want it do